# Android AsyncTask not response after some time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

Hi everyone I have a AsyncTask Class as

```
public class PostFileProc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    fileName1 = "somefile";


    try {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                fileName1));

        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                        + fileName1 + "\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }


    return null;
}
```

And i call this class in a service for each listener of Call broadcast or Incoming sms broadcast as

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
PostFileProc upFile = new PostFileProc();
                upFile.execute();
}
```

Then it will run 9-10 times successfully on incoming call and incoming sms but after that my service gets stop. And program will no longer response.
Please somebody help me on it, y is it so?

Comment: is it showing any error?

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace too?

Comment: Thanks @Wizard for reply. No its not showing any error. only service will get stoped

Comment: @Wizard, For Posting Json data in AsyncTask in same process is good. and it never get stopped but for posting file as shown above it get stop.

Comment: @user3310056 ok is app closes when service is stoped

Comment: Yes it get stop. as main app don't have any other GUI task to do.

Comment: @user3310056 did u tried debugging the code.

Comment: oh ok For this i have to debug it for a long time :(

Comment: Hey @Wizard find one issue. If network connection is closed then it get close.

Comment: Everytime a different file? I would flush() outputstream before trying to get a response. Are all files received on the server?

Comment: Yes every time a new file get received i=on the server.

Comment: @EliMoon then check for network connection before performing an operation

Comment: Add ex.printStackTrace(); in the catch. You are using InputStream.available() wich is only an estimated count. Further you declare a buffer of a certain size which you never change later in the loop but where you try to read more bytes from the stream then the buffer can contain. Better to determine filesize at forehand with File.length(). I think this causes your troubles. Is this code different from when you send json?

Comment: Thanks @Wizard Problem is solved. it shows error when I have not internet connection, at that time it produce an exception of unknown host. For this in catch I return null to AsyncTask. Now it works :)